# Imagining inside of complement set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm undergrad and writing from phone, so feel free to to correct following.
I have assignment to show that $( X\setminus A)^{\circ}= (X\setminus \bar A)$, where $A \subset X$.

Is it possible to graphically show left part? 
As I understand, it is inside of A union with X minus A circumference.

Comment: Do you mean $(X\setminus A)^\circ=(X\setminus\overline A)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. What are these called?

Comment: "interior" and "closure" perhaps?

Comment: I would be very wary of proving things about interiors and closures graphically. Lots of statements are intuitively plausible but wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in (X-A)^\circ$ iff there is some open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ with $U \subseteq X-A$
iff there is some open nhood $U$ of $x$ with $U \cap A  =\emptyset$
iff $x \notin \overline{A}$